# how can progress-bar listen value changes using flutter provider and update another widget?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, progress-bar, provider

**this is my provider **

```
MultiProvider(
   child: MyApp(),
   providers: [

  
  ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (BuildContext context)=> Downloads(),),)]
```

***this class implements notifylistner when i print out _progress  it all works properly
but the ui wiget does not rebuid to give out the outputs ***

```
class Downloads extends ChangeNotifier {


  int _progress= 0;

  int get progress => _progress;

  void setProgress(int p) {
    _progress = p;
    
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

*i have removed progress-bar widget to make it simple instead show output value*

```
class FileDownload extends StatelessWidget {
  const FileDownload({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: progessUi());
  }
}


class progessUi extends StatelessWidget {
  const progessUi({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final model = Provider.of<Downloads>(context);
    

    return Container(child: Text(model.progress.toString()));
  }
}
```

*this just a snippet where the calls to the Download function are made *

```
if (message['event'] == EV_PROGRESS) {
        
        Downloads().setProgress(message['progress']);

        
       
      }
      if (message['event'] == EV_DONE) {
        
        
        Downloads().setProgress(100);
        
       
      }
```